# HttpRequst with parameters not workign

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I am trying to make post request which works one way but other not.

Here is example how it works:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string baseUrl = "https://192.168.56.1:45456/User/GetToken";    
var response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl + "?username=*******&password=****", null);
```

but then when I try adding it "normal way" at the endpoint i am getting nulls.

Here is how I try doing it:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string baseUrl = "https://192.168.56.1:45456/User/GetToken";
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "username", "ALEKS13" }, { "password", "asd" } };
FormUrlEncodedContent encodedParameters = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

var response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl, encodedParameters);
```

What am I doing wrong in second code?

Here is receiving code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/User/GetToken")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken(string username, string password)
{
    return await Task.Run<IActionResult>(() =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
            return StatusCode(400);

        Models.User user = Models.User.Get(username);

        if (user.ValidatePassword(password))
            return StatusCode(200, APIAuthorization.GenerateToken(username));

        return StatusCode(403);
    });
}
```

Comment: Well in your first example, the parameters are in the URL. In the second example, the parameters are in the body of the request. You haven't shown us anything about the code that's receiving the request... presumably it's expecting the parameters to be in the query rather than in the body...

Comment: Side note, I really hope this code is for just testing and nothing more. Sending credentials (not hashed/salted) in plain view is disastrous and asking for problems.

Comment: @JonSkeet I Edited question and added receiver

Comment: @zaggler It is testing :)

Comment: Okay, we're getting there gradually... which version of ASP.NET is this? (Or ASP.NET Core?) Have you tried making a request with PostMan or similar? (Basically, work out whether the problem is in the request made by your client, or how the server responds to it.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for not replying. Year, request is working from postman and also from some online tester but not from my local application.

Comment: What I mean by "postman and online application" is that postman is working to the "192.168.56.1:45456" but then i tried publishing same application online and tested in on released version and there both postman and third party application tester are working too

Comment: Okay - so the next step is to try to see *exactly* what Postman is sending, and what your application is sending. I typically use Fiddler for that (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) - I'm not quite sure of its status since being bought by Telerik.